# Is there a more efficient way for grabbing the count of a model within the view? Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have Images. Each image has comments, and each comment has likes. In my view I'm wanting to display the number of likes a comment has by doing something like this:

```
@foreach ($images as image)
    <img href="$image->url">
    <div class="comment-box">
        @foreach ($image->comments as $comment)
            <div class="comment">
                <span class="comment-owner">{{ $comment->owner()->name }}</span>&nbsp;{{ $comment->body }}
                <div class="likes">
                      {{ $comment->likes()->count() }} // ** HERE IS MY N+1 PROBLEM **
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

However now I'm fetching a query each time there is a comment. There could be hundreds of comments on a page, so id be getting hundreds of queries just to find the `count()` for likes.

I believe there is a way you can grab the count in a controller by doing something like

```
DB::raw('count(*) as like_count')
```

but I do not know how to implement this in my situation. Can I put this kind of thing in my model so that I can always call something like `{{ $comment->likes()->like_count }}`? How can I make `$comment->likes->count()` work without having the N+1 problem?

Here is some more code:

Media Model

```
class Media extends Eloquent {
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment Model

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Media');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Like');
    }
}
```

Like Model

```
class Like extends Eloquent {
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Comment');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
public function imageViewer($id)
{
    $images = Media::with(['comments' => function($query) {
                  $query->with('likes');
              }])->where('resource_id', $id)->simplePaginate(1);
    return View::make('image-viewer', compact('images'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use blade's count like this `count($comment->likes)` assuming that `$comment->likes` gets the list of likes for a comment

```
@foreach ($images as image)
    <img href="$image->url">
    <div class="comment-box">
        @foreach ($image->comments as $comment)
            <div class="comment">
                <span class="comment-owner">{{ $comment->owner()->name }}</span>&nbsp;{{ $comment->body }}
                <div class="likes">
                      {{ count($comment->likes) }} 
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Thanks to @lukasgeiter for pointing out a mistake in the comments

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you can do `count($comment->likes())` vs `$comment->likes()->count()`

I'm very new to Laravel, thank you!

Comment: Actually `count($comment->likes())` will run a new query. `likes()` returns the relationship not the relationship results. It should be `count($comment->likes)` or `$comment->likes->count()` (makes no difference)

Comment: Yes that is also my problem then elsewhere on my project. Eloquent is tricky. Thank you @lukasgeiter